# Shopify CLI Raw Mode

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, shopify, shopify-cli

I am using macOS to create a Shopify App using the CLI. After creating the project, `npm run dev` works perfectly. However, when I create an extension, the `npm run dev` command returns an error. I have tried to read the link shared in the error log, but it doesn't seem to solve my issue. Here is the stack trace:

[image]

Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: You should share more details. What is Ink? What is the structure of your App? What is the output of the npm shopify info command? Seems like this is not a CLI error but one from something you are doing in your App?

Comment: The app is a freshly generated Shopify-CLI app, I use this command: `npm init @shopify/app@latest`. After the creation of the app, I create an extension with this command: `npm run shopify app generate extension`.
After this, I am starting the whole app with `npm run dev`. I don't write a single line of code.

Comment: You know the CLI team has a Github repo. You can tell them your troubles, provide the specific details of your install, and they will gladly fix the problem, as it probably affects more than just you. https://github.com/Shopify/cli

Comment: Thanks, I opened a report: https://github.com/Shopify/cli/issues/1649